# Google Map with Custom Makers

Tags: google-maps

I have created a custom marker and using the code below it works fine. The problem I have is that currently the custom marker is located on my desktop. But if I send the map to somebody how do I get the map to pickup the custom marker?

Thank you

Code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<title>DC11-51 Sitelist Example Campaign 2013719.html</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.2,-2.8);
var myOptions = {
zoom: 6,
center: latlng,
streetViewControl: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ms2/micons/red-dot.png', null, null, null,
new google.maps.Size(16, 16));
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.18001,-2.146337);
var Marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myLatLng,
map: map,
title: "3910",
icon: 'Destest.PNG'})
```

Comment: The best option is to put the icon at a publicly accessibly URL and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You could put both the html file and the custom marker into a folder and access the marker using the relative path. Whenever you want to send the code to anyone just zip the folder and send it so that html file and the marker icon are both sent.